# The meaning of the phrase I'll wait you out

Tags: phrases, expressions

I heard this phrase in the TV show Grimm. Does it mean that I'll wait until you come out of the house?

Comment: What was the context in which it was used in the show? If your statement about the context is correct, then you have answered your question yourself. (Not everyone gets to see NBC: is there a link you can give to an online video of it? Don't forget to give the timestamp where the phrase appears)

Comment: @AndrewLeach in the scene, one guy was in a house and another guy was outside. The latter said I'll wait out. They both had guns. I can't find a cut of these scene

Comment: You say in your question what it means, so what is the question?

Comment: @MattЭллен there's a question mark there

Answer (score 6):

No, that's not the basic meaning, though that could well be the implication in this particular case. It's just coincidence here that the transparent idiom 'wait out' has a particle (out) where the prepositional use is obviously not impossible. Contrast

> 'Let's wait the storm out in the hotel'.

[The basic senses](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wait+out) are:

> **wait something out**: to wait until something ends

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.]

> **wait somebody out** also **wait out somebody**: to allow time to go past until someone does something

[usually as an alternative to intervening in an undesired situation – or at least indicating that patience is being exercised]

[Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms]

Comment: This is a good answer. I think that there can also sometimes be an element of putting the person who is being waited out under siege—that is, waiting nearby until the person is forced to come out by necessity—although that sense is more forcefully expressed by the phrase "starve [somebody] out."

Answer (score 0):

Another meaning is to pressure someone, or some group to act in a certain way. If someone wants to do something and they can't do it until you leave, you then stay and wait them out, preventing them from accomplishing their goal.

Comment: Yes, an extension of what Sven says in the comment above. But please add a linked, attributed supporting reference for this (as in the answer above).